# what is wrong in this program?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, bubble-sort, tr24731

I wrote this simple bubble sort program using dynamic memory allocation. I am using VC++ compiler.

```
// bubble_sort.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void bubble_sort(int a[],int n);
int main()
{
    int *p,i;
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of array elements\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",(p+i));
    bubble_sort(p,5);
    printf("Sorted elements\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",p[i]);
    free(p);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void bubble_sort(int a[],int n)
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-1-i;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong in above program? Compiler shows following warnings. What does it mean?

```
Warning 1   warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.  

Warning 2   warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

Please help me.

Comment: The warnings tell you pretty much all you need to know. Which part is unclear?

Comment: Such questions are probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ But if the program does what it's supposed to then it is in a sense correct.

Comment: scanf has a lot of problems and should be avoided - http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the problem with your program. microsoft deprecated scanf function instead they introduce scanf_s function, which means they introduced security. To make compile your code there are two options.

1. use the scanf_s function instead of scan.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx )
2. or put macro "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" in the compiler settings.